# Event handling scroll event with a delay in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, throttling, debouncing

I was wondering if there is a way to add a debounce or throttle for this scroll listener event:

`private fun setupOnScrollChangedListener() { viewTreeObserver.addOnScrollChangedListener(onScrollChangedListener)}`

I wanted to work such that the event is not triggered every time the user scrolls to have a little bit of delay